# How can we manage the Relation between two table in POCO Entity?

Tags: razor, entity-framework-4.1, poco, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am a newbie to POCO.I have two tables like tb1 and tb2.Suppose we have a PK and FK relation between these tables.When it come to POCO CF how can we manage this relations?I have a done a sample by following a article.

```
 public abstract class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class Collaborator : Person
    {
        public int CollaboratorId { get; set; }
        public string ManagerCode { get; set; }
        public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
    }
```

Why they have used the abstract and virtual keywords? Can any one explain me the how can we manage the relations?

Comment: What article do you refer to? Let's see if we can help you understand any explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a model-first approach. You will want to use the Fluent API to define the relationships. Here is a [good article on how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx).